# Numpy array but each 1 is an element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know that `np.ones(3)` gives the following np array: `[1, 1, 1]`
is there a command in numpy that gives the following: `[[1], [1], [1]]`?

Alternatively, how do I turn the first array (not just for the size of 3, but for an n sized `np.ones()` array) into the form of the second one.

Comment: `np.ones((1, 3))` or `np.ones(3)[np.newaxis, :]`

Comment: Ah, np.ones((1, 3)) will give [[1, 1, 1]] so it should be np.ones((3, 1)), but I'm guessing you just did it off the top of your head so no stress

Comment: What's the shape of the desired result?

Comment: This is so basic that it really seems that you need a tutorial on numpy. SO is not a replacement for your own research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reshape sounds like an easy general solution here:

```py
np.ones(3).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Although you can always start with this:

```py
np.ones((3, 1))
```

These do the same thing

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
one=np.ones(3)
one.reshape(3,1,1)
```